# How to get file extension in Angular2

Tags: angular

My Requirement is to upload only files that ends with.pdf extension in Angular 2 is there any method to find the extension or like any split method in java.

Comment: Why dont try type script split()? See in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_split.htm

Comment: check here so many methods to do http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/get-file-extension/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you  can use split with pop for the file extension :

```
$(this).fileName.split('.').pop();
```

Comment: I did by like this  e.target.files[0].name.substr( e.target.files[0].name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)!="jpg"